# Map keys to values in pandas Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have this dictionary which I scraped from Wikipedia. The dictionary contains continents and their respective countries. For example:

```
theWorld = {'Asia': ['China', 'Malaysia'.. etc], 'Europe': ['Germany', 'Italy' ..etc]}
```

I am trying to make a dataframe using pandas to map a country to its continent. For example:

```
Country   Continent
China     Asia
Malaysia  Asia 
Germany   Europe
Ghana     Africa
```

and so on and so fort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to create the rows of the DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

theWorld = {'Asia': ['China', 'Malaysia'], 'Europe': ['Germany', 'Italy']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[v, k] for k, vs in theWorld.items() for v in vs], columns=['country', 'continent'])
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
    country continent
0     China      Asia
1  Malaysia      Asia
2   Germany    Europe
3     Italy    Europe
```

Additional resources:

- DataFrame data structure, [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/dsintro.html#dataframe)
- When to use a list comprehension, [here](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/)

Comment: thank you, that solved my problem. Would you be so kind to tell me what kind of reference I should look into for the solution you provided.

Comment: I don't understand list comprehension yet but I converted to normal loop and I kind of understood what you did exactly so thank you again.
data= []
for k, vs in theWorld.items():
    for v in vs:
        data.append([v,k])
print(data)

Comment: @Ozeus I linked some resources to list comprehensions, hope it helps

Comment: really helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in two steps, first invert the dictionary in a dict comprehension then create the dataframe using that country to continent mapping:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> the_world = {
...         'Asia': ['China', 'Malaysia'],
...         'Europe': ['Germany'],
...         'Africa': ['Ghana']
...     }
>>> country_to_continent = {
...         country: continent
...         for continent, countries in the_world.items() 
...         for country in countries
...     }
>>> country_to_continent
{'China': 'Asia', 'Malaysia': 'Asia', 'Germany': 'Europe', 'Ghana': 'Africa'}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(
...         data={
...             'Country': country_to_continent.keys(),
...             'Continent': country_to_continent.values()
...         })
>>> df
    Country Continent
0     China      Asia
1  Malaysia      Asia
2   Germany    Europe
3     Ghana    Africa
```